# How to fix I18n Ruby on Rails files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, internationalization, character-encoding

I sent english files to my client to be translated into korean. The files I sent had the following structure:

```
en:
  manage:
    title: "Manage Account"
    post_new_resume: "Post New Resume"
```

I tried to view the files in Textmate, and with UTF8 encoding, the files I got back look something this:

```
ko:
  manage:
    title: "��d ��"
    post_new_resume: "�̷¼� ���"
```

Basically gibberish. I also looked at the official translation files of rails from the I18n repository on github in UTF8 encoding and they actually show korean.

```
ko:
  units:
    byte: "바이트"
    kb: "킬로바이트"
    mb: "메가바이트"
```

I'm guessing that the files got damaged when the client sent them over (perhaps he saved them with the wrong encoding). My question is, what can I do to fix them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the `iconv` to solve the problem.
First, require it:

```
require 'iconv'
```

Then, write a method like this:

```
  def self.korean_to_utf(text)
    Iconv.iconv('UTF-8//IGNORE','euc-kr', text).join
  end
```

Then use that as needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you File => "Re-Open With Encoding" as UTF-8 in textmate?

Comment: that's exactly what I did. The product of that encoding is seen in my excerpt above (the gibberish one)